# input is getting overwritten python

Tags: python, input, overriding

```
T = int(input())
    while T > 0:
        rangeofnum = input().split(" ")
        starting = int(rangeofnum[0])
        ending = int(rangeofnum[1])
        print(starting)
        print(ending)
```

description: when input is given like:

```
input: 2
1 10
output:1
10
input: 3 5
output:3
5
```

but when I give input as follows:

```
input:2
1 10
3 5
output:1
10
```

Why ? and how to correct this?

I am a begginer to python?

Comment: Your examples are confusing, as they contain "input" and "output" but your code does not print those.  Show us the _actual_ code and the _actual_ input/output.

Comment: Consider accepting and upvoting answer when it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code you have given there should be two errors you should face:

1. Indentation error: You have given indent at the start of while statement unnecessarily.
2. Infinite loop: Your while loop never ends as the value of 'T' is always greater than '0' as you have decremented it.

As per your usage using a **for** loop with **range(0,T)** would be better. Below is the corrected code with while loop

```
T = int(input())
while T > 0:
    rangeofnum = input().split(" ")
    starting = int(rangeofnum[0])
    ending = int(rangeofnum[1])
    print(starting)
    print(ending)
    T -= 1
```

Comment: can you create a demo ? and show . Because, it isn't working for me

Comment: I have used 'repl'. It is working fine. Check it here https://repl.it/Iq1F

Comment: Ok, got it. It is version issue.

Comment: If you want this code to work in python 2.x use raw_input() instead of input().

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes to your code.

1. Indented your code properly
2. Change `input()` to `raw_input()` for this line `rangeofnum = input().split(" ")` line. If you are using Python 2.x.
3. Decrement T. So that, it will loop for T times.

**[>>Demo<<](https://ideone.com/msTBeC)**

Comment: Sorry @Ravi but you misunderstood the issue. 1) when I am giving inputting the code line by line it is working fine,But the problem is if I input to the console all at one the the values are getting overwitten. 2) If you still not understandding the problem the I will upload the pitures describing my problem. 3) thanks for your time

Comment: I didn't get you ?